# My controller is not updating my directive - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that shows a detail screen when a row is clicked.  I am trying to get the encounter to update.  Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('chatContainer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      encounter: '=',
      count: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/chat.container.html',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
  };
});
```

Here is the template to the directive:

```
<div class="span4 chat-container">
 <h5 class="chat-header">
  <span class="container">{{encounter.patient.firstName }} {{encounter.patient.lastName}}</span>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Here is where the directive is declared in the html:

```
<div chat-container encounter="selectedEncounter" count="count"></div>
```

And here is the controller that is called when the row is clicked.

```
angular.module('app').controller('EncounterCtrl', function ($scope, singleEncounter) {

  $scope.count = 500;

  $scope.selectedIndex = -1;

  $scope.selectedEncounter = -1;

  $scope.getSelectedRow = function($index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
    $scope.selectedEncounter = $scope.encounters[$scope.selectedIndex];
  };

  $scope.encounter = singleEncounter.selectedEncounter;
});
```

I get into the function `getSelectedRow()` and it changes the `selectedEncounter` to the correct encounter.  The binding does not bring the selection across to my `chatContainer`. I thought when I declared the `encounter` in the directive scope and gave it `=` as the scope type, it bound it, but I am missing something???

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$apply()` the change, however the logic for manipulating values should be inside the chatContainer directive rather than inside the controller.

Comment: Agreed, it should be in the directive, but how would $apply work?

Comment: What is calling the function `getSelectedRow()`? You haven't included all the code so I am guessing there is something outside of the angular framework and so the `$digest` loop is not running.

It is explained very well in this article http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/